# Rewrite jQuery function to Vanilla JS and optimize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First I want to apologize, because I am a bit newbie with JS and it's library jQuery. Basically I have written a javascript function that toggles my hamburger menu:

```
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
let menuOpen = false;
menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!menuOpen) {
    menuToggle.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuToggle.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

Now I want to rewrite this jQuery function to Vanilla JS

```
$(function() {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.inner-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
var searchElement = document.createElement(".inner-wrapper");
document.querySelector(".toggle").appendChild(searchElement);
searchElement.addEventListener("open", handleClick);
```

I would like to combine both functions if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `open` is not an event you can listen to, did you mean to use `click` instead?

Comment: Wrapper should open when I click the 'toggle', `$(function() {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.inner-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
  });
});`

Comment: I was referring to `searchElement.addEventListener("open", handleClick);` which should probably be `searchElement.addEventListener("click", handleClick);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this code of yours:

```js
menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!menuOpen) {
    menuToggle.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuToggle.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

can be simplified to this:

```js
menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuToggle.classList.toggle('open');
  menuOpen = !menuOpen;
});
```

Second, the equivalent vanilla JavaScript version of this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.inner-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

is this:

```js
document.querySelector('.toggle').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('.inner-wrapper').classList.toggle('open');
});
```

Finally, this code of yours has problems:

```js
var searchElement = document.createElement(".inner-wrapper");
document.querySelector(".toggle").appendChild(searchElement);
searchElement.addEventListener("open", handleClick);
```

There is no HTML element called ".inner-wrapper". You probably wanted to create an element with that class, something like this:

```
var searchElement = document.createElement("div"); // or any valid tag name
searchElement.className = 'inner-wrapper';
```

Also, there's no event called "open". You probably want that to be "click", and you probably want to target that to the ".toggle" element (not the '.inner-wrapper' element).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
searchElement.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

And your current code will add a event listener to `inner-wrapper` class instead of `toggle` class.

The javascript representation of your jQuery code has to be something like this

```
document.querySelector('.toggle').addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.querySelector('.inner-wrapper').classList.toggle('open');
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work for some reason. I think my code is wrong.
The logic is I have html button with class toggle, when I click on it -> inner wrapper.open will trigger

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. Now, how can I unite both? (the hamburger toggle and your code)

Comment: Yes you can replace your jquery code block with the code I put it in the ans, and check